# Donde encuentro el Favicon(icono) de la plantilla Adminlte 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy buscando el favicon.ico de la plantilla Adminlte 3, pero no lo encuentro por ningún sitio, antes solo se remplazaba la imagen, pero ahora no aparece en ningun lugar, ayuda por favor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres al incono que sale por defecto es esta
[Icono de AdminLTE 3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png)

pero si quiere convertirlo a un Favicon te recomiendo para el .icon de tu paguina. Podrias usar un convertido de PNG a .icon

Comment: Me refiero al icono anaranjado